# Is it irrational?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, infinity

Suppose I generate a number $0 < x < 1$. In general, after the decimal point, the first digit is $1$, the second is $0$, the third is $1$, etc. However, every digit in position $n$ has a $1/n$ chance of being $2$ instead. The tenths place, for example, must have a $2$. The number might look like this:

$$x = 0.221210101020101010101010101010121010101010101010101010101010...$$

(There are an infinite number of possible values of $x$. My question applies to any number in this set, excluding numbers where the digits begin to repeat interminably at a finite point, which has 0 probability of happening. Ex. not interested in 0.222222...)

Such a number doesn't seem to be rational, because $2$ will continue to pop up, even as it becomes less frequent. However, as the position $n$ of a digit approaches infinity, the probability of that digit being $2$ approaches $0$. It seems that as $n$ goes to infinity (and there *are* an infinite number of digits), the digits approach rational behavior, for lack of a  better phrase.

Would this number be irrational?

Clarification: What I am asking is whether a number would be considered irrational if its digits "approach repetition"; if they could be said to repeat interminably at infinity, but not at a finite point.

Comment: I think you should rephrase the Question to make it clearer that you are asking about the probability that this random variable will be a rational number.

Comment: This number *could* be rational and it *could* not. You didn't describe a single number. Your question is like saying "I generate my number by rolling a 6 sided die. Is the number even?". Well... it *could* be even, yes.

Comment: What does “considered irrational” mean?

Comment: @CarstenS simply "be irrational". What else would you think?

Comment: @user236182, I don't know. It might be that Kanaya's concept of an irrational number is fuzzy.

Comment: @CarstenS I've never seen a different definition for "irrational" (being used by anyone) from the usual one (in the usual real number sense).

Comment: @user236182 neither have I.

Answer (score 52):

If you get infinitely many 2s, but with arbitrarily large gaps between them, then your number is irrational.  This happens with probability one.  (See the [Borel-Cantelli theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma). I'm assuming your events with probability 1/n are independent, you didn't say that...)

But note if you use probabilities $1/n^2$ instead, then you get (with probability one) finitely many 2s, so your number is rational.

Comment: Because of the infinite sum? But is it really correct in terms of probability? Is  there some reference on the subject?

Comment: As I said, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma/

Comment: Fixed link: [en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma)

Comment: This is the best answer, I think, because all of the others seem to imply that if there were probability $\frac1{n^2}$ for each it would also be irrational with probability $1$, or even not talk about probabilities at all.

Comment: (Note to OP: In infinite spaces, "probability $0$" does not mean that it's impossible, only that it's less likely than anything with a positive probability. For example, if you pick a random number from the interval $[0,1]$, there is a probability $0$ that you pick the number $\frac12$ exactly, even though it's theoretically possible. That's because there's a $2\epsilon$ chance of picking a number in the interval $(\frac12-\epsilon,\frac12+\epsilon)$, and the probability of picking $\frac12$ has to be smaller than all of these. A similar thing is true for "probability $1$".)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger OP explicitly assumes that the decimal expansion isn't repeating. This directly rules out the rational case, regardless of probability-theoretical considerations... If OP meant to ask another question, then the question should be edited.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh. I didn't notice.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for; very interesting, thank you. And yes, the events are independent.

Comment: +1.  To show that the independence of the probability $\frac1n$ events matters, consider a case where first digit is $2$ and where the $n$th digit is $2$ with probability $\frac{n-1}{1}$ if the preceding digit is $2$, and where the $n$th digit is $2$ with probability $0$ if the preceding digit is not $2$

Comment: If the exponent $a$ of the event probability $n^{-a}$ is any number less than $-1$, is the number rational? Or is it required that $a < -2$?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander $\sum_n n^{-a}$ is finite for all real $a \gt 1$.  Consider $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} x^{-a}\, dx$

Comment: Fixed fixed link: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel-Cantelli_lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel-Cantelli_lemma)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger -- what is the difference between "less likely than anything with positive probability" and "impossible"?  Those two sound like the same thing to me.

Comment: @Malvolio: consider a motivating example: the uniform continuous distribution on the range $[0,1]$. We want to draw a distinction between the value $2$, which is "impossible" in the sense of not being in the range at all, and the value $0.5$, which cannot occur with any non-zero probability but which we don't normally want to call "impossible". If you're happy to say that *no* value is possible with a continuous distribution that's probably OK, because fortunately the word "possible" doesn't need to appear in any theorems, it's just not the usual terminology ;-)

Answer (score 15):

> Assume that the digits do not happen to start repeating interminably at a finite position (0.2210101010101010...), since the probability of this happening is 0.

Well then it is irrational... A rational number has a decimal expansion that is eventually periodoc. If you assume that it isn't eventually periodic, then you're ruling out the case that it's rational.

I think what you're confused about is that it doesn't matter how you generated your number; either it is rational, or it isn't. It is *possible* that your process will generate a rational number, though the probability that it does is indeed zero.

And for that matter you cannot speak of *the* number generated by this process; many different number can be generated by this process, some are rational, some aren't. Every single number will have probability zero of occurring, and yet your process will always yield *some* number...

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a number, it is a set of numbers. Probabilities don't make sense here, a number is part of your set or it isn't. The set is then $0.1010\ldots$ where some of the digits are replaced by $2$. One of the numbers in your set is $0.2222\ldots$, which is rational, another is $0.101010\ldots$, again rational. But it also contains the number where the $2$ show up only on positions that are perfect squares, i.e., $0.2012101012\ldots$, which isn't a repeating decimal and thus irrational.

Your set of numbers isn't countable, by the way, so it has to include transcendental numbers too (the set of algebraic numbers is countable).

Comment: I think this is the only correct answer. Moreover, I believe that many of the numbers in the set can't actually be constructed and therefore rely on the axiom of choice for their existence.

Answer (score 1):

That's **not rational**. And you don't write numbers by chance. Well, if a digit has certain 'probability' of appearing then it's not a fixed number.

You see one time the number may be 2 and another time it won't.
And since you say that though the provability approaches 0,  there is still the possibly, even if minute, that the number may be 2.